# Fateful golf game... in November

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story

"What a beautiful day!" I think to myself, contemplating that last round of golf with Oscar.

Checking into the hotel, Oscar confided in me, "Mike, there are some strange things happening. Whenever I make a phone call, I always hear an echo. This place is not safe..."

November is a crazy time to travel, but with Oscar being as worried as he is, I know this is not the time to hit the whiskey... What do I do?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

"What a beautiful day!" I think to myself, contemplating that last round of **g**olf with **O**scar.

Checking into the **h**otel, **O**scar confided in me, "**M**ike, there are some strange things happening. Whenever I make a phone call, I always hear an **e**cho. This place is not safe..."

**N**ovember is a crazy time to travel, but with **O**scar being as worried as he is, I know this is not the time to hit the **w**hiskey... What do I do?

You should...

> GO HOME NOW, as spelled out by the [NATO phonetic alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet) words in the story.

Comment: Spelled out by the NATO phonetic alphabet :P but I'm not going home, you can't make me

Comment: I knew I should have made it harder...

Comment: @ben-NabiyDerush These NATO based puzzles are easily noticeable and if there's nothing to hide them or make it unique, it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Yes. I had some thoughts about how to hide it better, but I did not take the time to implement. Thank you for the input on how to make things better next time.